# Unzip a file until i get a JPG,JPEG/PNG

Tags: php, file-upload, unzip

This is my function to unzip files. 
Now it is working for this, if i have a zip file contains only images and
it is not working for if i have a zipped file with a folder contain images

```
public function uploadZipImages($Orderpid, $OrderId)
{
    $valid_image_type = array('jpg,png');
    $valid_zip_type   = array('zip');
    $folder = DIR_WS_IMAGES_ORDERS . $OrderId . '/block_images';

    (isset($_POST['clearImages']) && ($_POST['clearImages'] == 1 || $_POST['clearImages'] == '1')) ? (exec('rm -rf '.$folder.'/*')) : (true);
    (!is_dir($folder)) ? (mkdir($folder, 0777)) : (true);

    foreach ($_POST['bulk_images'] as $block)
    {
        $total_count     = count($block);
        $zipimagename    = $block;
        $extension= substr(strrchr($zipimagename,'.'),1);
        for($i = 0; $i < $total_count; $i++)
        {
            $str_filename = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.-]", "_", $zipimagename);
            $file_name = $folder . '/' . $str_filename;
                move_uploaded_file(DIR_WS_IMAGES_ORDERS.$OrderId.'/'.$zipimagename, $file_name);
                 if (in_array($extension, $valid_image_type) || in_array($extension, $valid_zip_type))
                {   
                    if (in_array($extension, $valid_zip_type))
                    {
                        exec('unzip ' . DIR_WS_IMAGES_ORDERS.$OrderId.'/'.$zipimagename . ' -d ' . $folder . '/');
                        unlink($file_name);

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I know i have to change somewhere here                                     `exec('unzip ' . DIR_WS_IMAGES_ORDERS.$OrderId.'/'.$zipimagename . ' -d ' . $folder . '/');`
  By checking like to unzip until i found any jp,jpeg/png. How to do this?

Comment: You'll need to decompress to a temp directory, and then use a function to recursively search through the directory until you get a JPEG. You can either finish and just return one, or keep on going and add all images. Search for "directory recursion" here or on the php.net site for how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add parameter -j for unzip

```
exec('unzip ' . DIR_WS_IMAGES_ORDERS.$OrderId.'/'.$zipimagename . ' -j -d ' . $folder . '/');
```